# How can I detect all symmetries in a collection of large boolean arrays?

Tags: math, matrix, optimization, symmetry

I have a project that involves an unbounded grid of booleans. The grid is very sparsely populated in that I doubt that there will ever be more than 8 Trues in the entire grid. I'm optimizing a brute force problem, where the starting layout of Trues is used as a seed for further work. I want to ensure that I never run the same search on a pair of symmetrically identical boards.

Rotation, translation, and mirroring are all irrelevant symmetries. This matrix:

```
A 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 B 0
0 C 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

should be considered identical to:

```
0 0 0 B 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 C 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 A 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

A, B, and C are all "trues", but are labeled uniquely, here, so it's easier to see the transposition. The matrix has been mirrored, rotated, and translated. The matrices are logically infinite, but for the sake of symmetry elimination, they can be trimmed to the minimum dimensions that contain all the trues.

Whatever I end up using for this needs to be fast. Fortunately, the 8 trues in the matrix are likely to be confined to a 25x25 subsection of the space, so hopefully we can pull this off in a single pass.

I've contemplated finding the escribing rectangle, rotating and mirroring it so its dominant axis is horizontal and (any consistent set of requirements here), but it ends up being many passes in order to guarantee detection of all symmetries.

Comment: What does "likely" mean? Because as a programmer, "likely" means "not something you can count on to always be true" and so it's not something you write your code for. Also, what _generates_ the truth values, and can you change _that_ to generate just the list of coordinates that are true instead of the entire matrix? (or, as secondary output in addition to the matrix). Because that would near-trivialise your problem.

Comment: The probability of a true falling more than n distance of the most distant other true has an inverse forth-power relationship. I may have to search at a distance of 50 hops (a 25x25 board) from another true, but the odds of finding a solution there are 1/6250000. The odds on a 100x100 board drop to 1/100,000,000.

Comment: With rotations and reflections there are at most 8 possible versions of any starting grid, ignoring translations. Would it be possible to simply store a set of all configurations you’ve tried, including their rotations and reflections, and then check new configurations against this set before trying them?

Comment: @Sniggerfardimungus that does not answer the second, far more important question.

Comment: I'm using a hash aof xy vals as a ssparse matrix. This does not trivialize the problem. From the hash it _is_ easy to extract a list of 8 coords, but deciding whether those 8 points are a transposition of some previous configuration is show-stoppingly expensive if done naively. Sure, I could generate a grid, extract the 8 points in question, then find the bounding grid to allow me to place the corner of that grid at 0,0 for each of 8 rots/flips, generate some hash for those rotations.... then never see the project finish because of the psychotic amount of CPU required. I need fast, not easy.